# 2 fragments displayed dynamically in one tab of application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I build an application which has tabs in it, and using `ViewPager` to swipe between the tabs.

Is it possible that one tab will show `firstFragment`, and then when pressing a `Button` will show `firstFragment` and `secondFragment`?

Comment: Yes, we can do that you should create two containers in your First Child of tab and replace the fragment using getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: The thing is I don;t want to replace it.. I want to put 2 fargments together in the same tab on some situations..

Comment: you want to display 2 fragment in one screen under one tab?

Answer (score 0):

Of coarse you can. When you bind ViewPager to TabLayout you use adapter, which extends FragmentPagerAdapter, that adapter stores list of all fragments and layout texts. Just replace fragment in it and invalidate result. 
But, this should by done from Activity, which has ViewPager and TabLayout. 
Define interface in your first program, implement it in Activity and replace fragment on button click.

Comment: The thing is I don;t want to replace it.. I want to put 2 fargments together in the same tab on some situations..